# mongoimport E11000 duplicate key due to index

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a collection with the following fields:

```
name
type
color
```

I also have a unique index `name_1_type_1`.

Assuming a data set:

```js
[{
  name: "name1",
  type: "type1",
  color: "blue"
}, {
  name: "name2",
  type: "type1",
  color: "green"
}]
```

Using `mongoimport` I create the initial data set.

Now, I need to update the collection in order to achieve the following 3 goals:

1. insert new documents (e.g. `name1`-`type2` in snippet below)
2. update `color` in existing documents (e.g. `blue`->`red` in `name1` below)
3. append a new optional field `shape` in some documents

   ```js
   [
       {
           name: "name1",
           type: "type1",
           color: "red",
           shape: "circle"
       }, 
       {
           name: "name1",
           type: "type2",
           color: "green",
           shape: "rectangle"
       }
   ]
   ```

However, when executing `mongoimport --upsert` on the above json file, I get:

> error inserting documents: E11000 duplicate key error collection:
>   test.col1 index: name_1_type_1 dup key

Maybe I am using `mongoimport` in a wrong way.

How can I achieve the 3 above mentioned upsert goals using mongoimport?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have missed the [`--upsertFields`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsertFields) option. Without it `mongoimport` assumes you mean `_id` and especially if that is not present in the file being imported, then it's just trying to "insert" new items all the time. Hence the duplicate key error.

So if you specify the fields on which you have based the unique key:

```js
mongoimport -d database -c collection --upsert --upsertFields name,type input.json
```

Then you should get a result like the following:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f6332a49ec4ea8330063b6"),
        "name" : "name1",
        "type" : "type1",
        "color" : "red",
        "shape" : "circle"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f6332a49ec4ea8330063b7"),
        "name" : "name2",
        "type" : "type1",
        "color" : "green"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f633d4824b97f80d3714b1"),
        "name" : "name1",
        "type" : "type2",
        "color" : "green",
        "shape" : "rectangle"
}
```

Note that in modern releases the [`--upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsert) is implied when you use `--upsertFields`.

**N.B.** You might also need `--jsonArray` if your data is structured that way.